# Run ajax page in background (Android)

Tags: php, android, ajax, background-process

I'm trying to process database inserts in the background by calling a ajax request on page load. The problem I'm facing is that even if move from the page (the page on which the ajax request is made), it is still waiting for the process in the ajax page to complete.

I do not want anything to be output from the ajax page, just start and keep running until all the insert statements are complete. After researching on this subject, I found some solutions but they are not working in my case. I'm using the below code:

### index.php

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$.ajax({
   url:'ajax-page.php',
   success:function(ret)
   {
      // of no consequence as I'm not interested in output
   }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="somepage.php">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### ajax-page.php

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo (' ');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();

if(session_id())session_write_close();

// background process to start here
for($i=1; $i<=10;$i++)
{
    // perform insert query here
    sleep(1);
}
```

Now if I click **Click Me**, the navigation is waiting till the loop (the one in ajax page) has finished executing. Once all 10 records are inserted, the navigation proceeds.

AFAIK, I think I'm using all the suggested tricks via `ignore_user_abort()`, `flush()`, `session_write_close()` etc. Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding async: true in the jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'ajax-page.php',
  async: true,
  success: function() {
    // of no consequence as I'm not interested in output
  }
});
```

Comment: yeah it is, I hought that you might have overriden it somehow. Tried your code in my local apache server, and did not wait for the ajax-page loop to finish. Maybe the flush() does not get executed for some reason. Check the network pane in developer tools in the browser, to see if the request for ajax-page.php closes. 
Edit: Are you rinnging the pho on windows? Just read that flush might not work as expected on windows.

Comment: I'm using an app called as `AndroPHP` which works like `XAMPP` or `WAMP` on Android

Comment: well that might be the issue... try running it in a proper LAMP environment